# Multiple levels of DNS name compression

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm working on implementing a little [DNS stub server](https://github.com/doublez13/pystub), and I'm having trouble interpreting part of [DNS RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035).

```
The compression scheme allows a domain name in a message to be
represented as either:

   - a sequence of labels ending in a zero octet

   - a pointer

   - a sequence of labels ending with a pointer
```

Is it valid for a DNS name to follow multiple pointers? i.e a sequence of labels ending with a pointer to a sequence of labels ending with a pointer, potentially multiple times.
Or when using compression, it is only valid to have a sequence of labels ending with a pointer to a sequence of labels ending in a zero octet?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it valid for a DNS name to follow multiple pointers?

Yes and No.

Imagine you have the names (not writing the end dot for each):

- `example.com`
- `a.example.com`
- `b.a.example.com`
- `c.example.com.example.net`

They can be encoded, if in this order, as:

1. `example` + `com` + `\0` (2 labels + zero octet)
2. `a` + pointer to previous item
3. either:

   1. `b` + pointer to previous item (should be preferred, stronger compression)
   2. or `b` + `a` + pointer to first item
4. `c` + `example` + `com` + `example` + `net` + `\0`

In last case you can not do `c` + pointer to first `example.com` because if you do so, then with `example.com` you go up to the final `\0` and hence you are done, you encoded only `c.example.com` and NOT `c.example.com.example.net`.

Basically you can view compression as compressing suffixes. Not arbitrary compression anywhere in the name.

But third case variant 1 show you can follow multiple pointers: `b` + pointer to (`a` + pointer to (`example` + `com` + `\0`))

Section 4.1.4 of RFC 1035 has a full example:

```
For example, a datagram might need to use the domain names F.ISI.ARPA,
FOO.F.ISI.ARPA, ARPA, and the root.  Ignoring the other fields of the
message, these domain names might be represented as:

       +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    20 |           1           |           F           |
       +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    22 |           3           |           I           |
       +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    24 |           S           |           I           |
       +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    26 |           4           |           A           |
       +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    28 |           R           |           P           |
       +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    30 |           A           |           0           |
       +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+

       +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    40 |           3           |           F           |
       +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    42 |           O           |           O           |
       +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    44 | 1  1|                20                       |
       +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+

       +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    64 | 1  1|                26                       |
       +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+

       +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    92 |           0           |                       |
       +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+

The domain name for F.ISI.ARPA is shown at offset 20.  The domain name
FOO.F.ISI.ARPA is shown at offset 40; this definition uses a pointer to
concatenate a label for FOO to the previously defined F.ISI.ARPA.  The
domain name ARPA is defined at offset 64 using a pointer to the ARPA
component of the name F.ISI.ARPA at 20; note that this pointer relies on
ARPA being the last label in the string at 20.  The root domain name is
defined by a single octet of zeros at 92; the root domain name has no
labels.
```

Comment: So why is the answer "Yes and No"? Shouldn't it just be "Yes"?

Comment: Because it depends how you view things. You can have A where some parts point to B where in B some parts point to C. So what would be "multiple" pointers but if you want in sequence. On the other end, A can not point to 2 pointers, it is one or none, so in that sense it is NOT "multiple" pointers.